# Send address to the contract function from web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, addresses, remix

For example:

```
address[] storage;
function addAddress(address _a)
{
  storage.push(_a);
}
```

I need somehow to call it from the web3. When I'm trying to simply send some address 0x1234... to the function in Remix I'm getting an error:

> Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at
>   position 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to add quotation marks?
Try to insert `"0x123..."`

Comment: Dude, you are genius! Worked for the Remix, will work for the web3 as well I guess. thank you!

Comment: @porfavorite if the answer above resolved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: of course, as soon as I test in web3, didn't test yet